# Colocar Cifrão " R$ " em angular

Tags: angularjs

Preciso colocar um R$ em AngularJs. O Código é esse, alguem poderia me ajudar e esta devolvendo um valor no value.

```js
$scope.addValue = function(el) {
    var element = el.currentTarget.attributes["ng-model"].nodeValue;
    var status = el.currentTarget.checked;
    if (status == true) {
        $scope.formData.saldoItensSelecionados = Number($scope.formData.saldoItensSelecionados) + Number(scope["resultSimulacao"]["tipsaa1VO"][element]);
    } else {
        $scope.formData.saldoItensSelecionados = Number($scope.formData.saldoItensSelecionados) - Number(scope["resultSimulacao"]["tipsaa1VO"][element]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode fazer essa exibição diretamente em sua view através do código:

```
{{meuvalor | currency: 'R$'}}
```

Esse código seria para ser usado no momento que for exibir. Ele mesmo irá se encarregar de deixar o seu valor em formato de moeda. Por exemplo, se o seu `$scope` estiver assim:

```
$scope.meuvalor = 10;
```

A exibição será: `R$10,00`

---

Respondendo a segunda dúvida, postada nos comentários:

deste modo:

```
<input type="text" name="meuvalor" ng-model="meuvalor" />
```

No entanto, o input **NÃO** irá receber o valor `R$`, apenas o numeral `10`. Para que ele também tenha o R$, você deve usar algum serviço de máscara ou um directive para manipular o prefixo.

Se fizer isso, tome cuidado, pois você pode salvar o dado em um modo que não será reconhecível pela estrutura que lhe passei acima.

Comment: Vlw Cara Ajudou muito, Mais tenho um problema ainda o input principal não recebe angular angular expression {{}} só recebe ng-model como eu poderia fazer isso ?

Comment: Eu editei a resposta para responder isso. Ficou claro agora?

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a documentação oficial do angular, sessão [i18n and l10n](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n):

> Angular supports i18n/l10n for [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), [number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) and
>   [currency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) filters. All localizable Angular components depend on
>   locale-specific rule sets managed by the [$locale service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$locale).
>
> There a few examples that showcase how to use Angular filters with
>   various locale rule sets in the [i18n/e2e directory](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/i18n/e2e) of the Angular
>   source code.
>   Angular separates number and datetime format rule sets into different files, each file for a particular locale. You can find a list of currently supported locales [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale).

Então:

```
<html ng-app>
 <head>
….
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="i18n/angular-locale_pr-br.js"></script>

   <script>{{ 1000 | currency }}</script>
 </head>
</html>
```